# Using Datalist Items within a nested repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datarepeater, asprepeater

I have this code for a blog which is nesting a repeater control within a datalist.

I'm trying to assign the alt tags of the repeater control images to be the title of the post coming through the datalist however, it will not let me though this because it has a different data source.

Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Here's my code:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="DataList1" ItemStyle-CssClass="row1BackgroundBlock" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
<!-- <%#Eval("PostId")%> post -->
<div class="dateBox"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#ffffff" Font-Bold="False" Text='<%# Eval("PublicationDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' CssClass="postmetadata"></asp:Label></div>
<div class="roundPanelStack">
<h2><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Engine2010.Blog.BlogLinksManager.GetFullPostsLinks((int)Eval("PostId"), (object)Eval("FURL")) %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink></h2>
<ul><li class="postBy">Posted in <a href="<%#CommonFunctions.GetTreeURL(146).ToString() + "?categoryid=" + Eval("CategoryID") %>"><%#Eval("CategoryName")%></a> by <%#Eval("Author")%></li><li class="last">{<%# Engine2010.Blog.PostComment.GetAllByPostId(int.Parse(Eval("PostId").ToString()), 766).Rows.Count.ToString()%> comments}</li></ul>

<div class="thumbWindow">
<div style="border:7px solid #fff;display:block;height:95px;left:1px;position:absolute;top:1px;width:95px;z-index:5;"></div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="repImgs" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img class="thumb_view" src="/uploads/images/Blog/<%# Eval("Directory").ToString().Substring(Eval("Directory").ToString().LastIndexOf("\\")+1) %>/<%# Eval("Name") %>" alt="" border="0" width="143" height="143" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <img src="/includes/images/general/default.jpg" alt="Default" border="0" width="110" height="110" />
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>

<p>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#CommonFunctions.Remove_HTML_Tags(Eval("Description").ToString()) %>' CssClass="entry"></asp:Label>
</p>

<div class="linksMore">
<asp:HyperLink ID="FullStoryLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Engine2010.Blog.BlogLinksManager.GetFullPostsLinks((int)Eval("PostId"), (object)Eval("FURL")) %>' CssClass="fullstory">Read Full Post</asp:HyperLink><a class="spacer">&nbsp;//&nbsp;</a><asp:HyperLink ID="CommentsLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Engine2010.Blog.BlogLinksManager.GetFullPostsLinks((int)Eval("PostId"), (object)Eval("FURL")) + "#comment" %>' CssClass="comments">Comment</asp:HyperLink>

</div>


</div>
<!-- /first post -->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Backend:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repImages = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("repImgs");                          // Child repeater with images for room
        string amenText = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[7].ToString();
          DirectoryInfo folderBr = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/images/Blog/") + amenText);
        // List<Engine2010.ImageObj> imageObjs = folderBr.GetImagesInPath();

        if (folderBr.Exists)
          {
              repImages.DataSource = folderBr.GetFiles("thumb*.*");                                                        // Bind room images to child repeater  
                repImages.DataBind();

              if (repImages.Items.Count == 0)
              {
                  PlaceHolder placeholder1 = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1");
                  placeholder1.Visible = true;
              }
          }
          else {
              PlaceHolder placeholder1 = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1");
              placeholder1.Visible = true;
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **ItemDataBound** event of your DataList1 after binding `repImages` repater control, iterate through each item by using `RepeaterItem` and then find your img control and assign title in alt tag like this -

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repImages = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("repImgs"); 
        string amenText = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[7].ToString();
        DirectoryInfo folderBr = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/images/Blog/") + amenText);

        if (folderBr.Exists)
        {
            repImages.DataSource = folderBr.GetFiles("thumb*.*");      // Bind room images to child repeater  
            repImages.DataBind();

            if (repImages.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                PlaceHolder placeholder1 = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1");
                placeholder1.Visible = true;
            }

            // Iterate thru each item of your child repeate control.
            foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItem in repImages.Items)
            {
                if (repeaterItem.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
                    repeaterItem.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    ((HtmlImage)(repeaterItem.FindControl("imgId"))).Alt = amenText; // Assume amenText is the title of your post
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            PlaceHolder placeholder1 = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1");
            placeholder1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

good luck...